# Generic class where type can Parse strings

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I want to create a generic class where the type of the class can Parse strings.

I want to use this class for any class that has a static function Parse(string),
like System.Int32, System.Double, but also for classes like System.Guid. They all have a static Parse function

So my class needs a where clause that constraints my generic type to types with a Parse function

I'd like to use it like this:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> : where T : ??? what to do ???
{
     private List<T> addedItems = new List<T>()

     public void Add(T item)
     {
          this.AddedItems.Add(item);
     }

     public void Add(string itemAsTxt) 
     {
         T item = T.Parse(itemAsTxt);
         this.Add(item);
     }
}
```

What to write in the where clause?

Comment: There is no generic constraint which will do that.  It would have to be runtime validation using reflection.

Comment: I rarely say this and someone else might know better, but I'm pretty sure you can't do that since all the classes you want to be a viable option have no common base type or interface. C# doesn't do its type matching how you need it to do this (what you might call duck typing)

Comment: my bid for that is impossible using where clause, you cant even enumerate possible classes

Comment: Imagine there exist different `Parse`-methods in another assembly with different parameters. E.g. `MyType.Parse(string, int, string, anotherType, ...)`. Even *if* you could add a constraint to "have a `Parse`-method", there´s no way to define one that fits all possiblle overloads or just a single one or whatever. **So what should your class actually *do* with those types?** You can´t call that method as mentioned before, because you don´t have *any* information about their arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not happy with the answers that would use reflection to do the Parsing.

I prefer a solution that is type safe, so the compiler would complain about the a missing Parse function.

Normally you would constraint to a class that has an interface. But as others said, there is no common interface. Come to think of it I don't need an interface, I need a function that I can call

So my solution would be to insist that creators would provide a delegate to the Parse Function that would parse a string to type `T`

```
class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    public MyGenericClass(Func<string, T> parseFunc)
    {
         this.parseFunc = parseFunc;
    }

    private readonly Func<string, T> parseFunc;

    public void Add(string txt) 
    {
        this.Add(parseFunc(txt));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyGenericClass<Guid> x = new MyGenericClass<Guid>(txt => Guid.Parse(txt));
MyGenericClass<int> y = new MyGenericClass<int> (txt => System.Int32.Parse(txt));
```

The answer is simpler than I thought

Comment: An interface requirement on a generic parameter doesn't work for static functions anyway; interfaces can't dictate static functions. I'm surprised that was never mentioned yet. This is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but will this do the trick?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guid g = DoParse<Guid>("33531071-c52b-48f5-b0e4-ea3c554b8d23");

    }

    public static T DoParse<T>(string value) 
    {
        T result = default(T);
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse");
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {

            ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), null);

            object[] parametersArray = new object[] { value };
            result = (T)methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do that at compile-time at all. All those methods don´t have *anything* in common except their names. They neither are defined in any common interface nor have they the same parameters.

Imagine you have your own method that accidently has that name, but does something completely different. In addition it´s also an instance-method:

```
class MyType
{
    void Parse() { ... }
}
```

As you can see that method don´t even has *any* argument, making it hard to find any common logic between - say - int.Parse(myString)`and`myInstanceOfMyType.Parse()`.

But even *if* you could do that. What would you do with the `item`? There´s not much as there´s nothing in common between them. In particular it´s impossible to *call* the methpd, as they are completely different.

You could loop all types with a similar method at runtime however:

```
var types = allAssemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                .Where(x => x.GetMethod("Parse") != null);
```

But be aware that this yields to an `AmbiguousMatchException` if more than one method per type exists with the name, this is when the method is overloaded.